# Controller action value not passing to javascript with Gon gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, httparty

This issue has he pretty baffled. I have a simple form that has a `remote: true` method. Im simply trying to get the users input from the form and send it to javascript for further use.

**/main/app/controllers/queries_controller.rb**

In the controller when I use pry all the values I expect to be there are there, but when it comes to gon value being send to javascript its always `undefined`.

```
def index
    search_term = params[:query]
    @stats = Query.api_response(search_term)
    gon.stats = @stats

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        format.html
    end
  end
```

**/main/app/models/query.rb**

```
    class Query < ApplicationRecord

        def self.api_response(term)
            url = "https://api.ritekit.com/v1/stats/history/#{term}?tags=&client_id="
            api = "1234567890123456789"
            return HTTParty.get(url + api)
         end        
 end
```

**views/shared/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag queries_path, method: :get, remote: true do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :query %><br>
    <%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
<% end %>
```

**/main/app/views/queries/index.js.erb**

This value is undefined when sent to the console.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log(gon.stats)
});
```

**/main/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <%= include_gon %>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/api/sum().js"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
```

**I have also tried**

```
<%= content_tag "div", id: "foobar", data: {value: @stats} do %><% end %>
```

and got `undefined` as well when I used jQuery to access it.

Im really stumped on this one, and its bothering me because its been a few days and i'm still not getting intended result. Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Try using `` insead "" for the API adress, where you inject the term: url = "https://api.ritekit.com/v1/stats/history/#{term}?tags=&client_id=" Also, add https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug byebug to your gemfiles, and then add 'byebug' right after you sign on the search_team params. If its not empty, put the 'byebug' tag one line below and see the response. I assume your api isn't giving anything back. // Edit: didn't see that you are using gon gem. Still, try it out. The author in the answer below down knows more about gon. Greetings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know `gon` does not allow to that. Or at least there is no out-of-the-box mechanism for updating `gon` variable via ajax request. They have `gon.watch`, but it is for other use cases.

And I think you don't need it. When your server respond with `.js.erb` template you already have access to data in javascript. You can access `@stats` variable as `<%= @stats %>`. No need to use `gon` there.

Comment: You are 100% right, I was able to access the value i needed without using the gone gem in the js.erb file using `<%= raw @stats.to_json %>`. Thanks for staring me in the right direction, I truly appreciate it!